# WebBrowser1 problem with external web app

Tags: java, javascript, applet, browser

the external Application works good in IE so i know the problem is inside My App.

The external web app is java applet and java script based, and the problem im experiensing is when the java applet tryes to run a java script. The Applet opens a seconday window with a java script and tryes to do some operations but then i just stops. And my Application seems to be non responsive and i have to restart it.

in IE it works just fine, the java applet opens the window does its thing and updates back in to the Applet.

anyone know why it not working in the webBrowser control?

Answer (score 0):

Two scenerio could be possible:

1) whenever we opens the web site in web browser control any previous session(authentication) cookie is not being reused, and new session will be created.

2) you have to override the eventhandler webBrowser_newWindow to allow opening the new window.

Comment: it might be cookie related as it seems it opens a IE window not a new webBrowser window.